# omit categories from main navigation menu

Tags: categories, menus, navigation

I realize this is an extremely basic question. I've created several basic Wordpress sites and do not recall ever having this issue, but I can't find an answer anywhere so far to something that seems like it should be so easy.

My navigation menu shows blog categories, and I can't figure out how to get rid of them. Here's the site: http://letthisbeenough.com. The categories are busyness and striving. Why are they showing up on the menu, and how can I only show pages there, no categories?

Also, why is Home showing up twice?

I've created a new menu (Appearance, Menus), set it to display as my "primary menu," and saved it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Appearance -> Menus and manage your menu there. You should be able to choose what will appear in the menu.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't working, thus the problem. But I figured out it was a new feature of my theme, and I have to do it within the theme settings.